# Просмотр изменений в Базе Данных

Tags: node.js, socket.io, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Как можно средствами Node.js и Socket.io следить за изменением информации в Базе данных?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте систему очередей сообщений (например RabbitMQ или Redis Pub/Sub). В коде, который добавляет запись в БД также отправляйте соответствующее сообщение в очередь сообщений.

Сделайте также чтобы ваше приложение (socket.io) отслеживало новые сообщения в очереди (для [rabbitmq](http://www.squaremobius.net/rabbit.js/), для [redis pub/sub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis#publish-subscribe)) и отправляло их клиенту.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно написать на ноде модуль, который будет обеспечивать:

- подключение и взаимодействие с базой данных
- создание веб-сокетного сервера
- обработку команд, приходящих по веб-сокетному соединению

Практически любой чат подходит как пример такой реализации.

Comment: Это понятно, уже реализовано, но я имею ввиду что бы когда в БД в какой то строке были изменения он их выводил.
Например: есть таблица в которой постоянно изменяются данные, скажем дата и ссылки, и сокет считывал последние 10 записей которые изменились и выводил!

Comment: @chambo почему бы приложению самому не дергать собственные события, когда оно обновляет бд?

Comment: Там большая система, я тоже предлогал, мне отказали(